# How to put a cross mark in a check box instead of a tick mark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a jsp with checkboxes which needs to marked with a cross instead of tick, I have seen some codes but I am not able to figure out how is it exactly done.

Could you write a simple code to implement it.

Comment: @SoumyaMukherji Ahh That's exact catch.

Comment: I saw that question but was unable to understand and execute it

Comment: loads and loads of duplicates of this. I've picked one to flag it, but if you [search the site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+custom+checkbox) you'll find a whole bunch more.

Comment: not sure why you'd have troulbe with the question I linked; the top answer points to about a dozen separate tutorials... surely one of them would be easy enough to follow?